# dplyr in r ... Differences in responses of multiple groups to two questions

Tags: r, dplyr

Plenty of problems like this on stackoverflow, but nothing yielding an answer

Consider a poll with questions Q2 and Q4 ... I want the difference in the number of
people giving the 3 possible answers ... e.g.

```
df<-tribble(
  ~Area,~Question,~Section,~Response,~G1,~G2,
  "King","Q2","polibreak","Yes",59.7, 72.5,
  "King","Q2","polibreak","No",22.3, 10.1,
  "King","Q2","polibreak","Undecided", 17.9, 17.4, 
  "King","Q4","polibreak","Yes",61.8, 70.0, 
  "King","Q4","polibreak","No",19.7, 10.0, 
  "King","Q4","polibreak","Undecided", 18.5, 20.0, 
)
wanted<-tribble(
  ~Area,~Section,~Response,~G1,~G2,
  "King","polibreak","Yes",-2.1, 2.5,
  "King","polibreak","No",2.6, 0.1,
  "King","polibreak","Undecided", -0.6, -2.6, 
)
```

I've tried various grouping and diff using a lag, based on other
answers but nothing really gives what I want.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Question,Response) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(. - lag(., default=0)))
```

The actual data has more groups than G1 and G2 and more areas, but this data should suffice.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via the `diff` function, assuming that each combination of Area, Section, and Response has only two Questions:

```
df |> 
  group_by(Area, Section, Response) |> 
  arrange(desc(Question)) |> 
  summarize(across(c(G1, G2), diff)) |>
  ungroup()

  Area  Section   Response      G1     G2
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 King  polibreak No         2.6    0.100
2 King  polibreak Undecided -0.600 -2.6  
3 King  polibreak Yes       -2.10   2.5
```

Note that I `arrange` the Questions in descending order so that the signs of the differences match the desired outcome in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... but I get an error ...
```
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(c(G1, G2), diff)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! `.fns` must be a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
```

Comment: Ah ... I need diff.default

Comment: Many thanks  ... subtle